# how to start puma server after code is deployed using capistrano on ec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-16.04

I have setup the capistrano script to deploy on staging. I cant seem to find a way to restart the puma server as deployment gets completed and to restart the puma server if server is rebooted for any reason.

I am using rails 4.2 and Ubuntu 16.04 on ec2 server. I tried upstart script with puma-manager but I think its not supported on ubuntu 16.04.

I followed this link for puma-manager http://blog.peterkw.me/automatic-start-for-puma-rails-and-postgresql/

my deploy.rb file is

```
lock "3.8.0"

set :application, 'pb-ruby'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:url/pb-ruby.git' # Edit this to match your repository
set :branch, :staging_new
set :stages, %w(staging,dev_org)
set :default_stage, "dev_org"
set :deploy_to, '/home/pb/pb-ruby'
set :pty, true
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}
set :bundle_binstubs, nil
set :keep_releases, 5
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.3.0' # Edit this if you are using MRI Ruby

set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"    #accept array for multi-bind
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/config/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'staging'))
set :puma_threads, [0, 8]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_preload_app, false
```

Capfile is:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'


require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets' # for asset handling add
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations' # for running migrations
require 'capistrano/puma'
```

puma.rb file is

```
workers 1

# Min and Max threads per worker
threads 1, 6

app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)  
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "staging"  
environment rails_env

# Set up socket location
bind "unix:///home/pb/pb-ruby/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"

# Logging
stdout_redirect "/home/pb/pb-ruby/shared/log/puma.stdout.log", "/home/pb/pb-ruby/shared/log/puma.stderr.log", true

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "/home/pb/pb-ruby/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "/home/pb/pb-ruby/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state"  
activate_control_app

on_worker_boot do  
  require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("/home/pb/pb-ruby/shared/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this once. I ended up adding the rails server instance as a daemon using this command every time I deploy

`cd current/app_dir
rails s -d -p 3000 -e 'production'`

PS: I kill the current running rails instance before doing this